# Error al crear Troncal SIP elastix

Tags: enlace

Necesito su orientacion, tengo un problema al crear una nueva troncal SIP, agrego todos los parametros que se necesitan pero a la hora de crearla me arroja el siguiente error

```
FATAL ERROR
DB Error: already exists

INSERT INTO sip (id, keyword, data, flags) values ('tr-peer-2',?,?,'0')
Trace Back
Array
(
[0] => Array
( 
[file] => /var/www/html/admin/modules/core/functions.inc.php
[line] => 4794
[function] => die_freepbx
[args] => Array
(
[0] => DB Error: already existsINSERT INTO sip (id, keyword, data, flags) values 
('tr-peer-2',?,?,'0')
)

) 

[1] => Array
(
[file] => /var/www/html/admin/modules/core/functions.inc.php
.............
```

Segun puedo comprender es un problema en la base de datos que la troncal de encuentra duplicada, ya que al parecer el enlace anterior no se elimino por completo de la base de datos, y lo que supongo se podria realizar es entrar a la base de datos buscar la tabla que contiene los datos de la troncal y borrarlos.
Me podria orientar de como podria realizar esto?